# function variables not defined error

Tags: javascript

I am calling a function in Javascript and passing few parameters(title, subTitle, text). I debugged and checked their values are being passed to it, I want to use them in a callback method but their values are not defined in that scope. How to solve this?

```
 function geocodeQuery(query, title, subTitle, text) {
        //If search manager is not defined, load the search module.
        if (!searchManager) {
            //Create an instance of the search manager and call the geocodeQuery function again.
            Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Search', function () {
                searchManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Search.SearchManager(map);
                geocodeQuery(query);
            });
        } else {
            var searchRequest = {
                where: query,
                callback: function (r) {
                    //Add the first result to the map and zoom into it.
                    if (r && r.results && r.results.length > 0) {
                        var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(r.results[0].location,
                            {
                                title: title,
                                subTitle: subTitle,
                                text: text
                            });
                        map.entities.push(pin);

                        map.setView({ bounds: r.results[0].bestView });
                    }
                },
                errorCallback: function (e) {
                    //If there is an error, alert the user about it.
                    alert("No results found.");
                }
            };

            //Make the geocode request.
            searchManager.geocode(searchRequest);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you should replace 
geocodeQuery(query);
with
geocodeQuery(query,title, subTitle, text); 
in load_module callback

Comment: @VasylMoskalov It worked Thanks!